# Kendo Grid Data Item To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo UI Framework with ASP.NET MVC 4. I have a grid that is bound via AJAX of IEnumerable.  Each row is of type Objects.

There is a button that once clicked for the selected row, i would like to pass that Object for that row to Controller/Action which will then return a new html page.

I could pass the id and then get the object server side but using the ID is not secure in this application and prefer to send the object.

How do i send the object from View A to Controller/Action -> View B?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: As @ataravati said, provide some of your code. I'm having the same issue